# Destructure to two separate variables

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a quick way to destructure an object so that it store into two different groups? for example:

```
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c:3, d: 4, e: 5};
const {a, b} = obj;
// store the rest of the properties that weren't destructed above
const {otherStuff} = obj;
```

Some stuff to note:

1. I know what are the first properties i need from the object.
2. I don't know what the rest of the properties are that weren't destructured.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const {a, b, ...otherStuff} = obj;
```

Comment: See `rest/spread` object destructuring [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring)

Answer (score 1):

You can use destructuring with rest parameter syntax `...` to get the rest of the object in another variable:

```js
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c:3, d: 4, e: 5};
const {a, b, ...otherStuff} = obj;

console.log(otherStuff);
```