# Destructure object into 2 separate objects in one call

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2020

is there a 1-step way to destructure object into 2 objects using some defined set of props.

For example, having initial object

```
const obj = {
prop1: "Prop1",
prop2: "Prop2",
prop3: "Prop3",
....
}
```

i'd like to do smth like:

```
const { firstObj: { prop1, prop2, prop3 }, secondObj: { ...rest }} = obj;
```

So far I have to do it in 2 steps like here [Destructure to two separate variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58014955/destructure-to-two-separate-variables):

1. destructure obj prop1, prop2, prop3 and ...rest
2. save {prop1, prop2, prop3 } as firstObj, {...rest} as secondObj

Comment: `ecmascript-2020`: _"Only use this tag where the question specifically relates to new features or technical changes provided in ECMAScript 2020."_ - Destructuring is part of ECMAScript 2015

Answer (score 2):

You could destructure and take a new object with default values.

Even it is working, it is better to use separate assignments for `firstObj`.

```js
const
    obj = { prop1: "Prop1", prop2: "Prop2", prop3: "Prop3", prop4: "Prop4", prop5: "Prop5" },
    { prop1, prop2, prop3, firstObj = { prop1, prop2, prop3 }, ...secondObj } = obj;

console.log(firstObj);
console.log(secondObj);
```

Comment: Indeed, it's an interesting & still valid way. Thanks.